# How can I user struct and interface to get different json construction in Golang

Tags: json, go, struct, interface

#### It can gets different json construction:

#### type 1:

```
{"errcode": 0, "errmsg": "OK", "data": {"name": "Jolly", "age": 19}}
```

#### type 2:

```
{"errcode": 0, "errmsg": "OK", "data": {"friend": "Lisa", "country": "US"}}
```

I knew I can get those by define 4 structs like:

```
type Base1 struct {
    ErrCode int    `json:"errcode"`
    ErrMsg  string `json:"errmsg"`
    Data    Person `json:"data"`
}
type Person struct {
    Age   int    `json:"age"`
    Name  string `json:"name"`
}
```

and

```
type Base2 struct {
    ErrCode int    `json:"errcode"`
    ErrMsg  string `json:"errmsg"`
    Data    Info   `json:"data"`
}
type Info struct {
    Friend   string    `json:"friend"`
    Country  string    `json:"country"`
}
```

If I want to load json 1, just type `data := Base1{}`

If I want to load json 2, just type `data := Base2{}`

But I want to know how can I get them by 3 structs and using interface, because I have lots of APIs that provide json construction, their first layer all same as struct `Base`

like

```
type Base struct {
    ErrCode int         `json:"errcode"`
    ErrMsg  string      `json:"errmsg"`
    Data    interface   `json:"data"`
}
```

How to write the `data := Base{...}` and let it become struct Base1, Base2

Comment: Great, it solves the problem. Thank you.